# Push changed files by release:prepare

Tags: java, maven

I have a class like this:

```
public final class MyClass {

    private static String VERSION = "1.0.0-SNAPSHOT";
}
```

By **maven-replacer-plugin** plugin I'm changing **VERSION** field value and setting maven project current version (during **process-sources** phase).

Also I'm using **maven-release-plugin** plugin to do release.
As a initial step I'm calling **release:prepare** to change 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT (development) version to release version (it also commuting to git repo with tagging release commit/version). Please have a look to release plugin config:

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-release-plugin.version}</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.scm</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-scm-provider-gitexe</artifactId>
                        <version>${maven-scm-provider-gitexe.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <configuration>
                    <releaseProfiles>release</releaseProfiles>
                    <preparationGoals>clean process-sources</preparationGoals>
                    <goals>deploy</goals>
                    <arguments>-DskipTests=true</arguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

For **preparationGoals** are chosen **clean process-sources**, which means that **VERSION** field value is successfully changing to release version (e.g. from 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT to 1.0.0).

**release:prepare** goal is commuting only .pom files, MyClass is changing, but not committing.

Any idea how to tell release plugin to commit MyClass as well with .pom files?